# Temporary scale or multiply values from a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still learning RoR and I'm facing this problem that I don't know how to approach or solve (in an elegant and RoR-friendly way)

For context, I have a cooking recipe (controller, view, model) full CRUD, everything working fine. Now, this recipe is for, let's say, 10 people. But this particular time, I will have to cook for 15 people, or perhaps just 5 people. It's not a new recipe, it's just a scale/ratio of a recipe.

Should I create a new class to handle this temporary item?
Create a non-CRUD action?

Any ideas or comments are welcome =)
Thanks!

Comment: Use a query parameter to pass it. `/recipes/1?portions=12`

Comment: Someone voted to close this b/c it is "too broad". What might help is to show the approach you have tried and explain where you are stuck. However, since I'm here... creating a new class for this seems unnecessary. If the recipe is to be prepared for a different number of people, your application logic should adjust the proportions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `concern` (or a view helper depending on whether I want to calculate at controller level or view).

`Concerns` have to be placed in the `concern` folder in the controller view (***app/controllers/concerns***)

Then loaded in your `ApplicationController` (***application_controller.rb***) to be accessible into all your other controllers.

In your case, a concern would look something like this

```
module RecipeScale
  def recipe_scale(ingredient_value, init_numb_of_people, new_numb_of_people)
    return ( ingredient_value / init_numb_of_people ) * new_numb_of_people
  end
end
```

Then load this to your app by adding in ***application_controller.rb***: `include RecipeScale`

Now you can call `recipe_scale` in your app.

Assumptions: all numbers are floats, if not the case you may have to cast them properly.

Comment: Why do this as a controller concern and not on the model level? Your suggested code was also full of errors.

Comment: @max why not? I agree that you can also make it a view helper or some JS in the view that will handle those cases, however, I think that this type of logic should be in the controller so you can stack API faster